# change home_url and site_url but don't redirect to home_url and site_url on load

Tags: redirect, site-url, home-url

I have two domains `uat1.example.com` and `uat2.example.com` pointing to the same wordpress installation.

I want to change the home_url and site_url for all links on the website to `uat2.example.com`, but it should not redirect to `uat2.example.com` if the request comes on `uat1.example.com`,

So suppose someone visits my website, uat1.example.com; it should load it. But all links on the web page then should point to `uat2.example.com`. So if the User lands on the page using `uat1.example.com` and clicks on any link it will send the user to `uat2.example.com`; that is ok.

I tried putting this in config:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://uat2.example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://uat2.example.com');
```

but when I visit `uat1.example.com` it is redirecting me to `uat2.example.com`, which is obvious. but I don't want that.

Do we have any trick so that home_url and site_url remains `uat2.example.com` only? But when I visit `uat1.example.com`, it doesn't redirect me to `uat1.example.com` and still consider `uat2.example.com` as home_url for all links on that page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `WP_SITEURL` and `WP_HOME` in  `wp-config.php` file. 
Please add below code.

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

In your server SSL setup then used below code

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Comment: As I mentioned, it is already added but this will then change all links on the page to requesting domain. I want to keep my all links pointing to uat2.example.com even though user visits uat1.example.com